# Reusing a View on MVVM pattern with EFCore

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-core

I'm working with EF Core and MVVM pattern, and I'm not sure how to proceed on how to create a "reusable" view.

I have a view with a menu strip with common operations (CRUD and filtering) and a `DataGrid` that would be filled via EF Core. I have a bunch of different models (all of which inherit a simple base model class with a single `int ID` property), and I need to display my data.

Now, according to DRY, since the views are practically identical, I shouldn't create a different view for each model, just create a generic view and fill it accordingly. Also, I've read here that viewmodels aren't usually reusable, so I would need one viewmodel for each model. And here's my question.

When creating my view, I was taught this pattern:

```
public class StockView : Window
{
    private StockViewModel _viewModel;

    public StockView(StockViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel ?? new StockViewModel();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

However, that would mean this view would only accept `StockViewModel`, so I wouldn't be able to reuse it. I've tried creating an abstract viewmodel base for all viewmodels to inherit from, and created my generic view as

```
public class GenericView : Window
{
    private ViewModelBase _viewModel;

    public GenericView(ViewModelBase viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel ?? new ViewModelBase();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

But now, I won't be able to access any of the viewmodel methods that would fetch me data asynchronously. Async abstract methods aren't allowed, and I tried creating a method that would a service class that would return me my data, but I can't use it either:

```
public class StockService
{
    private MyDbContext _context = new MyDbContextFactory().CreateContext();
    
    public async Task<List<Stock>>GetStocksAsync()
    {
        return await _context.STOCKs.Select(x=>x).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
    public abstract List<EntityBase> GetAllData();
}
```

```
public class StockViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public override List<EntityBase> GetAll()
    {
        var stockServ= new StockService();
        return stockServ.GetStocksAsync().Result; //<==== this doesn't compile as the method expect List<EntityBase> but it returns List<Stock>
    }
}
```

How would I be able to reuse a view for different viewmodels, then?

Comment: Who taught you that? Use DataTemplates instead. Whoever it was they were in a WinForms mind set to create a property of a Vm in a window is like creating another DataContext, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Async abstract methods aren't allowed ...

No, but `async` is an implementation detail. An abstact class or an interface may still define a method that returns a `Task<T>` that you can then *implement* asynchronously:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T>
{
    public abstract Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItems();
}

public class StockViewModel : BaseViewModel<Stock>
{
    public override async Task<IEnumerable<Stock>> GetItems()
    {
        await ...
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, but then my generic view would be `public StandardListView(ViewModelBase<EntityBase> viewModel)`. How would I instantiate a new view for the stock model? `new StandardListView(new StockViewModel());` isn't valid

Comment: It depends on how you generally instantiate your views and view models but how about something like `new View() {  DataContext = anyViewModel }` ? No need to use dependency injection in the views.

Comment: That did the trick. Rather than inject the viewmodel, I'm setting it during instantiation. Now, all I had to do was expose some common properties/methods inherited from the viewmodel base, and it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: Alright, now a different issue has arisen... I cannot call any method inherited from `ViewModelBase<EntityBase>` because I can't upcast `StockViewModel` to `ViewModelBase<Stock>`

Comment: I'm thinking of setting two properties on instantiation, DataContext itself, and the type the entity type the DataContext should expect. That would work, I think.

Comment: @ASousa: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. If you post the link to it here, I'll try to help you.